# Redirect page with JavaScript after 5 seconds but do not stop other code from executing

Tags: javascript, html, asynchronous, timeout, sleep

I want to redirect to a specific URL after 5 seconds but I don't want it to block or stop all the other code on the page to execute. The 5 seconds should give enough time for all the other code on the page to fire first before redirecting. I cannot wrap the entire page in a `setTimeout` block. So basically, I can place the "wait 5 second and then redirect code" anywhere on the page and the code on the rest of the page will still fire.

The code I currently have does not work:

```
console.log(1);
await new Promise(resolve =\> setTimeout(resolve, 5000));
console.log(2);
```

That code does not work because `console.log(2)` should fire immediately after `console.log(1)` and should not be waiting for the timeout.

Comment: Any place on the page: `setTimeout(() => console.log(2),5000)` will fire 5 seconds after the code is reached and not blocking any other code.
`window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => setTimeout(() => console.log(2),5000))` will fire 5 seconds after the page has loaded not blocking any other script on the page

Answer (score 0):

`setTimeout(<redirect_function>,5000)`